# Inputting null values through np.select's "default" parameter

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Trying to write values to a column given certain conditions, with default as Null value with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': list('ABCDE')})

cond1 = df['col'].eq('A')
cond2 = df['col'].isin(['B', 'E'])

df['new_col'] = np.select([cond1, cond2], ['foo', 'bar'], default=np.NaN)
```

But it gives `'nan'` as string value in the column.

```
df['new_col'].unique()
#array(['foo', 'bar', 'nan'], dtype=object)
```

Is there a way to directly change it to null from this code?

Comment: How do you know it's a string value?

Comment: df.col.value_counts() should not show me the count of null values. But it does. It shows the count for "nan".

Comment: Start looking through the rest of your code then, since (although pandas is buggy) it's far more likely the error is somewhere in the code generating conditions or choices that isn't shown here.

Comment: Just as I said earlier, the other codes are fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the correct solution, which uses `None` as the default value:

```
df['new_col'] = np.select([cond1, cond2], ['foo', 'bar'], default=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested it myself and it behaves properly. Check output of `np.select(conditions,choices,default=np.nan)` manually, maybe there're "NaN" strings in `choices` somewhere.

Try specifying `dropna=True` manually in `.value_counts()`, maybe it's set to default False smh?

What I tested it with:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

iris = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')
iris['sepal_length'] = np.select(iris.values[:,:4].T>5, iris.values[:,:4].T, default=np.nan)

print(iris['sepal_length'].value_counts())
print(iris.sepal_length.value_counts(dropna=False))
```

Comment: I still have the same problem. There are no "nan" in choices. Not sure how are you not able to replicate. I am using pandas version 0.20.3. Which version are you using?

Comment: Also tested with `df.col.value_counts(dropna=True)`. Still the same.

Comment: Using 0.23.4. Added code I used to test it with. Interestingly enough, using default="NaN" still uses NaN correctly for me.

Comment: I don't know how you are not able to replicate. Just tried doing a `df.col.isnull().sum()`. It shows 0 null values for me. Is this a version related issue? Numpy version here is 1.13.1.

Comment: Well, it's easy to check if you run the piece of code I edited into the answer. If it works, then there must be something along the way, like a forced typecasting to string or smth idk.